# Given a canvas object, how can I get a scaled down "version" of it as an image/Base64-encoded byte array?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to take "screenshots" of the current browser window.  I would like to save the screenshot as Base64 encoded data which can later be used to create an html img.  For example, I might want to save the String that canvas.toDataURL() returns in the browser's local storage, and retrieve it later.

The following code works fine:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        localStorage.setItem('screenshot', JSON.stringify(canvas.toDataURL()));
    }
});
```

I can later retrieve it and create an image from it, for example using Angular:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{imgData}}"/>
```

What I want to do though, is have a scaled down version of the screenshot.  I can simply scale the resulting image using CSS, but I want to save storage space.  In other words, I want the String encoding to represent an image that is, for example, 200 pixels wide instead of (say) 1000 pixels wide.  I do not care about the quality of the image.

This is the closest I've come:

```
saveScreenshot = function(name, scaleFactor) {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                //canvas.width *= scaleFactor;
                //canvas.height *= scaleFactor;
                localStorage.setItem('screenshot', JSON.stringify(canvas.toDataURL()));
            }
            img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        }
    });
}
```

This *almost* works - the "picture" is scaled correctly, but the resulting image is still the same size as the original, with the rest of the space apparently filled in with transparent pixels.

If I uncomment the 2 lines above which set the canvas' height and width, then the image is the right size, but it's all blank.

I feel like I'm close - what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.toDataURL` will always capture the entire canvas, so to get a smaller image you must  create a second smaller canvas:

```
var scaledCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
var scaledContext=scaledCanvas.getContext('2d');
scaledCanvas.width=canvas.width*scaleFactor;
scaledCanvas.height=canvas.height*scaleFactor;
```

Then scale the second canvas and draw the main canvas onto the second canvas

```
scaledContext.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
scaledContext.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
```

And finally export that second canvas as a dataURL.

```
var dataURL = scaledCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Warning: untested code above...but it should put you on the right track!

Comment: is `scaleFactor` a percentage?